# Response.Redirect does not work in CD in Sitecore Web form for marketer Custom save action

Tags: wffm

I am using Sitecore 8.1 updated 2.
I am redirecting web user to success or failure page based on the condition in WFFM custom save action.In cm server it's working fine in CD it's showing wffm thank message.
Do we have any config setting in CD that we need to enable.

Comment: No answer, but just a thought: for redirecting on success there are better ways than a save action. You can use the pipelines for that. More info here: https://ggullentops.blogspot.be/2016/07/sitecore-wffm-act-on-success.html. Can elaborate in an answer if this is an option for you.

Comment: Is the "Client Action" field of your Save Action checked? When this field is checked, the save action is executed on the CD server.

Comment: Are you sure you are fully published? It sounds like CM and CD have different set of actions. Can you also log into Sitecore desktop and switch to the web database. Are the save actions the same on the form in web?